# simultaneous (async) work - getting msg receiving and placing order/selling in auto bot w websocket

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio, ws

'''
I would like to get async working for purchasing ordering while continuously getting realtime price update by websocket receving. However, when I execute the code below, I found the result like the below, which is in a order, not simultaneously.
so, want to do work function - Purchase() when 'if' is made, while restarting Fucntion - Main() to  get the realtime price at the same time. can you help to advice?

KRW-BTC 50493000.0 65190905111.72767
구매할 때가 되었다
구매할 때가 되었다2
구매할 때가 되었다3
KRW-ETH 3728000.0 42981406234.81617
KRW-ETH 3729000.0 42981416234.80089
KRW-BTC 50532000.0 65191256384.92567
구매할 때가 되었다
구매할 때가 되었다2
구매할 때가 되었다3
'''

```
async def main(wm):
i=int(0)
while i<1 : 
    global code, close, volume
    data = wm.get()
    code, close, volume=data['code'], data['trade_price'], data['acc_trade_price']
    #timestamp=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(data['trade_timestamp'] / 1000)
    #open = data['opening_price']
    #high=data['high_price']
    #low=data['low_price']
    print(code, close , volume)
    if code == 'KRW-BTC' and close >50200000:
        await purchase()
    
            
async def purchase():
    print("구매할 때가 되었다")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("구매할 때가 되었다2")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("구매할 때가 되었다3")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)  


if __name__ == "__main__":
    wm = pyupbit.WebSocketManager("ticker", coinlist)
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    tasks = loop.create_task(main(wm))

    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(tasks)
        loop.run_forever()        
    except KeyboardInterrupt as exc:
        logging.info('Quit.')
    finally:
        print("Closing Loop")
        loop.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

the results are in sequence because the next iteration of the while loop cannot run until `await purchase()` returns, the easiest way to get more concurrency is to treat your `main` function as a "worker" e.g.

```py
import asyncio
import operator
import pyupbit

async def worker(wm):
    while True: 
        data = await asyncio.to_thread(wm.get)
        code, close, volume = operator.itemgetter('code', 'trade_price', 'acc_trade_price')(data)
        if code == 'KRW-BTC' and close > 50200000:
            await purchase()

WORKERS = 10  # scale as desired

async def main():
    wm = pyupbit.WebSocketManager("ticker", coinlist)
    workers = [asyncio.create_task(worker(wm)) for _ in range(WORKERS)]
    await asyncio.gather(*workers)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

the above will allow 10 `purchase()`'s to be awaited concurrently, and u can increase it as u see fit